# Is there a reason to keep Lily's shop open?

Tags: dex

Is there a reason to keep Lily's shop open? She just sells junk and healing items, which, now that I have the Nanite Blood Infusion, I don't need the latter. I already took Shen, so I can't get her other services, which don't seem to have a gameplay purpose?

She doesn't seem to purchase junk for any more than anyone else, like Speedy...

Is there any gameplay reason to keep her available by not killing / knocking out her Bouncers for the EXP, at least just now?